# How many perfect squares exist (multiples of $24$)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> How many positive perfect squares less than $10^6$ are multiples of 24?

I quickly realized:

$$24 = 2^{3}*3*5^0$$

$$10^6 = 2^6 * 5^6*3^0$$

We are finding numbers in the form $24(k^2)$.

But I don't see a way to do this?

Comment: I do not entirely understand what you are suggesting ... $24k^2$ is never a perfect square. But $24\cdot 6\cdot k^2$ is.

Comment: @String, how is $144k^2$ the same as finding perfect square multiples of $24$?

Answer (score 5):

If a perfect square is a multiple of $24=3\cdot 2^3$, then is a multiple of $144=3^2\cdot 2^4$, too.

Now we have to solve
$$144\le144k^2\le 10^6$$
or
$$12\le 12k\le 10^3$$
which yields
$$1\le k \le 83$$

Comment: Good idea, but you need to fix your factorization of 24... $2^3\cdot 3^1$.  Means you need a multiple of $2^4\cdot 3^2$.

Comment: Hurry and maths are incompatible ;) Fixed.

Comment: (+1) "f a perfect square is a multiple of 24=3⋅23, then is a multiple of 144=32⋅24, too." But why is this true?

Comment: @Lebes: The prime factors must be squared. $$N=p_1^{k_1}\cdot p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_s^{k_s}$$ is a square iff $k_1,k_2,...,k_s$ are all divisible by $2$.